# VS Code python extension is not activated

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

Hi I found that the Python extension is not properly activated in the VS Code.

The variable names are not properly recognized (highlighted) as shown below

[image]

In addition, it does not prompt out the variable name for auto-completion.

[image]

But I think I have checked the auto-completion.

[image]

I tried version v2023.16.0 and v2024.2.1. Both do not work for me.
Python version: Python 3.8.18
OS version: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved this by `pyrightconfig.json` file in the workspace.

```html
{
    "include": [
        "codes"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This was possible caused by not choosing python environment.

You can use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose your python interpreter.

You could [read document about python](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_working-with-python-interpreters) for more details.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your help! But I have selected the correct interpreter I think. https://hkustconnect-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/yruanaf_connect_ust_hk/ESNTrnuAYExGojtsSn7GkQMBU31LS3Ic8qn0t1FbFAlmyQ?e=P2gfKc
I think the difference between the working case and not working case is that there is no little bubble on the corner of "{}". Is there anything else I can check? Thanks again!